# How to change the order if dates are same

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Query is order by Date and visit type.

If there are two different types of visits on same date then order should be changed.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Visits v
Order by 
v.visitdate ,
,CASE
 WHEN v.[VisitType] = 6 THEN 1
 WHEN v.[VisitType] = 5 THEN 2
 WHEN v.[VisitType] = 3 THEN 3
 WHEN v.[VisitType] = 4 THEN 4
 WHEN v.[VisitType] = 2 THEN 5
 WHEN v.[VisitType] = 1 THEN 6
END
```

In following example, there are two different types of visits on same date 05 Nov.

```
+-------------+--------+
|    Date     |  Type  |
+-------------+--------+
| 30-Oct-2015 | 2      |
| 30-Oct-2015 | 2      |
| 04-Nov-2015 | 1      |
| 05-Nov-2015 | 2      |
| 05-Nov-2015 | 1      |
+-------------+--------+
```

So the order of last two lines should be other way around. For now i need to worry about type 1 and 2 and rest would stay in same order.

```
+-------------+--------+
|    Date     |  Type  |
+-------------+--------+
| 30-Oct-2015 | 2      |
| 30-Oct-2015 | 2      |
| 04-Nov-2015 | 1      |
| 05-Nov-2015 | 1      |
| 05-Nov-2015 | 2      |
+-------------+--------+
```

Just wondering if its possible to do that.

Comment: Let me guess: visitdate has time part? `SELECT * FROM Visits v
Order by 
CAST(v.visitdate AS DATE),
CASE
WHEN v.[VisitType] = 2 THEN 1
WHEN v.[VisitType] = 1 THEN 2
END`

Comment: You can also do `order by v.visitdate, v.[VisitType] DESC`, i.e. no need for a `case` expression.

Comment: why can't i add a screen shot?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (The use of `[` seems to indicate T-SQL/SQL Server). Sample data is better added as formatted text, not as screenshots

Comment: @user1263981 - because screen shots are infinitely worse than *text*, especially if it comes to providing us with sample data and/or expected results. With text we can copy and paste it straight into a query window and start working. With a picture, you're giving us not just a problem to help you solve, but also extra typing practice that we've not asked for. (Bonus points if sample data is provided as valid `INSERT` statement(s))

Comment: With your update - isn't this simply a case of sorting by `Type` *before* `Date` rather than after?

Comment: no............................

Comment: can you provide the sample data with all columns

Comment: I don't understand. In your ORDER BY you say order by date and for same dates type 2 before type 1. And then you complain that you get the data sorted exactly like stated? What the heck?

Comment: sorry i think my question was not very clear. I have updated my question and try to make it more simple so everyone can understand it. Sorry...

Comment: Er, no. Your edit doesn't change anything. In your CASE construct you explicitely say how you want your data ordered and then you complain that it gets ordered that way. If you want another order then change the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written:

```
Visit = 1 Status = 2
```

and you want order by date and visitType, where you want before visit and then status. So, in simple way...

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Visits v
Order by 
v.visitdate, v.visitType
```

Comment: You want transcode 1 and 2 with name (Visit and Status)?

Comment: After your update, my answer doesn't change. You have put a different order explicited in CASE statement. But you want before Visit and then Status (in your final example). So I don't know your real aim. Please make better your question

Answer (score 0):

Although your `Type` is missing from your query, here is my suggestion:

```
SELECT *
FROM Visits v
ORDER BY VisitDate ASC
    ,CASE 
        WHEN v.[VisitType] = 6 THEN 1
        WHEN v.[VisitType] = 5 THEN 2
        WHEN v.[VisitType] = 3 THEN 3
        WHEN v.[VisitType] = 4 THEN 4
        WHEN v.[VisitType] = 2 THEN 5
        WHEN v.[VisitType] = 1 THEN 6
    END DESC
```

Here is a sample [SQLFiddle with how the code works on your sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f97f/1).

You don't need a complex `CASE` statement in your `ORDER BY` in order to display the data in this format. There are simpler ways.

Comment: I think type ASC no DESC. After "Should be" at the same the he wants before 1 and then 2

Comment: @user1263981 You are either not explaining your question correctly or you haven't taken a look at my SQLFiddle. Also, your `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` has no point, it achieves the same result as a regular `ORDER BY DESC`, except with more code, explicitly treating "all" scenarios

Comment: pls look at the case statement again.

Comment: @user1263981 Take a look at my SQLFiddle now, it has been updated to give you the result you want and it will work correctly when adding the rest of the values, `3,4,5,6` etc.